Paste as body text in Word Document unless it is a table
I have set up some templates where the users can copy from elsewhere and paste into the document and the pasted text will always default to body text using the script below which works great except when they want to paste a table in.  I have also removed the paste options from the ribbon along with a lot of other options to control what users are able to change.
When tables are pasted in they would like to keep the formatting of a table (ideally using the destination formatting but one step at a time)
From my research I have found that it is not possible to know if the copied text is a table  as the clipboard doesn't store that specific information in word (unless this has changed since the posts I have read) and I have not found anything that would suggest the paste event has anything that would identify it as a table either unless it is pasted into a blank document first. I am wondering if it is possible to identify whether it is a table from the source as long as the source is still open obviously, using VBA somehow?
Nothing in my research so far has suggested it is possible identify a table is being copied/pasted but I thought I would ask anyway
Dim newText As String
    Dim clipboardText As String


Selection.TypeText vbCrLf
Selection.Style = "Body Text"

    clipboardText = GetClipboardText()

    newText = vbCrLf & clipboardText
     
    ' Applying formatting to the pasted text
    With Selection
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 1
        .Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End With

   ' Pasting text at the current selection
    Selection.TypeText newText


Why are you applying all of that manual formatting on top of the Body Text style? If that is how Body Text is supposed to look, why haven’t you modified the style to have those settings?

Don't you copy the table (only) from Excel? If from Excel, I think it is possible (even if not so simple) to determine if the clipboard contains a table. I certainly can check if it is a Range and I think it must be possible to determine if the respective range is a table, or part of a table... What do you want, from this point of view? If the range in the clipboard is part of a table, to paste all the table? All the table DataBodyRange? Only the copied range (keeping their original format)? Or, what? Besides that, it is not a matter of "Word clipboard", it is a matter of Windows Clipboard

@TimothyRylatt for some reason the text wasn't consistently pasting as Body Text so I put the style settings in as a catch for those ones.

@FaneDuru most often the table will be coming from another word document.

Why not simply use Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pasteandformat and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype

For table formatting to work correctly the underlying style must be Normal, which must also match the document defaults.

It doesn't take all that long to execute something like this, and you might be able to do some or all of your table formatting in the temp document, perhaps (haven't checked) inserting into the actual document using .FormattedText.
But maybe too laggy for all the times they aren't inserting a table.
Function IncludesATable() As Boolean
Dim d As Word.Document
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Goto problem
With Application.Documents.Add(Visible:False)
  .Content.Paste
  IncludesATable = (.Content.Tables.Count > 0)
  .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End With

problem:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function

' Test routine
Sub TableNoTable()
If IncludesATable Then
  Selection.TypeText "There's a table."
Else
  Selection.TypeText "There isn't a table."
End If
End Sub


Thanks @jonsson this will solve the issue for pasting the tables no matter the source.  It doesn't seem to be too laggy but will see if I get any complaints as the document is built using copy and paste currently.

You did not answer my clarifications question, after some time...
So, the next solution checks if in clipboard it is (part of) an Excel table (listObject). It can be easily adapted to check if all the table is copied, the table DataBodyRange or something else if logically/clearly defined...
The code is designed to work in VBA7, 64 bit version. It can be adapted to work in 32bit version, too.

Copy the next code in a new standard module:

Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal lngFormat As Long) As LongPtr 'modificat din Long in Any
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardFormatNameA Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long


Sub testIsTableInClipboard() 'place a table (part) in memory and TEST IF CLIPBOARD CONTAINS a table (part)
   Debug.Print IsTableInClipboard
End Sub                      'then copy something else (text, an ordinary range etc.) and test it again...

'or paste the clipboard content using Excel table format:
Sub testPasteExcelTable() 'paste the table formatted as Excel table:
    If IsTableInClipboard Then
        Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False 'Pastes and formats a Microsoft Excel table.
        'expression. PasteExcelTable( _LinkedToExcel_ , _WordFormatting_ , _RTF_ ) 'method's parameters
    End If
End Sub

Function IsTableInClipboard() As Boolean 'it checks if an EXCEL TABLE (
    Dim dataHwnd As LongPtr                 'pointer to clipboard data
    Dim intOffset As Integer                'for parsing clipboard data
    Dim strClipData As String               'clipboard data
    Dim strGetClipRange As String           'return range address (wb and ws)
    Dim rngFormatID As Long                 'id number for link format (Range)
    Dim strWorkbookName As String           'the range workbook to be used to set Excel Session!
    Const intMaxSize As Integer = 256       'limit for r1c1 to a1 conversion
    
    rngFormatID = getRangeFormatID("Link")      'extracting the id number for "link" format (Range)
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then GoTo safeExit 'go to code end to unlock and close clipboard and exit

    dataHwnd = GetClipboardData(rngFormatID)    'pointer to clipboard data
    If dataHwnd = CLngPtr(0) Then GoTo safeExit 'could not allocate memory
    
    dataHwnd = GlobalLock(dataHwnd)             'lock clipboard memory, so we can reference
    If IsNull(dataHwnd) Then GoTo safeExit      'if could not lock clipboard memory
    
    intOffset = 0                               'start parsing data
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)            'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset)        'copy pointer to string
    If strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize) Then GoTo safeExit 'not excel range on clipboard
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    If strClipData <> "Excel" Then GoTo safeExit           'not excel range on clipboard
    
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)           'next offset
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)                       'reset string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset)        'book and sheet next to it
     strWorkbookName = VBA.Replace(Split(strClipData, "]")(0), "[", "") 'the workbook name where from the range belongs!
     'Debug.Print strWorkbookName: Stop
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    strGetClipRange = "'" & strClipData & "'!"             'get workbookbook and sheet
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)    'next offset
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)                'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset) 'range next
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    strGetClipRange = strGetClipRange & strClipData 'add range to extracted string (xlR1C1 style)
    
    'Dim exApp As Excel.Application, ClipBRange As Excel.Range, tbl As Excel.ListObject 'i tneeds reference to Excel...
    Dim exApp As Object, ClipBRange As Object, tbl As Object
    Set exApp = GetObject(strWorkbookName).Application
     strGetClipRange = exApp.ConvertFormula(strGetClipRange, xlR1C1, xlA1)    'convert the range style
     Set ClipBRange = exApp.Range(strGetClipRange)    'range in a1 style
     Set tbl = ClipBRange.ListObject                  'check if ClipBRange is part of an Excel table
     If Not tbl Is Nothing Then                       'if tbl is not nothing
        Call GlobalUnlock(dataHwnd) 'unlock clipboard memory
        Call CloseClipboard         'close ClipBoard
        Set exApp = Nothing         'release Excel app from memory
        IsTableInClipboard = True: Exit Function      'make it True and exit function
     End If
safeExit:
    Call GlobalUnlock(dataHwnd)     'unlock clipboard memory
    Call CloseClipboard             'close ClipBoard
End Function

Function getRangeFormatID(strFormatName As String) As Long 'it looks that for a range the ID is not a constant...
    Dim FormatId As Long, retFormat As String, formatLength As Integer
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then Exit Function   'could not open clipboard
    formatLength = Len(strFormatName) + 30        'we only need a couple extra to make sure there isn't more
    FormatId = 0 'initialized at zero
    Do
        retFormat = Space(formatLength)           'initialize string
        GetClipboardFormatNameA FormatId, retFormat, formatLength 'get the id name
        retFormat = Trim(retFormat)               'trim spaces
        If retFormat <> "" Then                   'if some string remained
            retFormat = Left(retFormat, Len(retFormat) - 1) 'get rid of terminal character
            If retFormat = strFormatName Then     'if it matches strFormatName
                getRangeFormatID = FormatId       'return the correspondent id number
                Exit Do                           'exit Loop
            End If
        End If
        FormatId = EnumClipboardFormats(FormatId) 'get the next id number
    Loop Until FormatId = 0                       'exit the loop after last id number
    Call CloseClipboard                           'close clipboard
End Function


Place an Excel table, or part of it in clipboard, then play with testIsTableInClipboard testing sub. It will return True. Then, copy something else (strings, files, ordinary range etc.) and run it again. This time it will return False

Each code line is commented in a way to make it easily understood (I think). If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarificatons.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

@jonsson Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

There is nothing in the question to indicate that Excel is the source of the table.

@FaneDuru, FWIW I just noticed that I didn't see your comment, which by accident referenced me rather than the OP.
